# Tomcat/Liferay Hot Deploy not functioning

Tags: tomcat, deployment, liferay

I have looked through some of the similar threads but could not find answer to my problem.

My liferay tomcat server was working fine, including the hot deploy, until i changed the server.xml to add some new resources. After restarting the server, adding new wars in the deploy folder does not create the exploded folders in the webapps folder. The server does not even recognize then as I don't even see anything on the server console. Here is the relevant part from my server.xml:

```
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" deployXML="false"
      name="localhost" unpackWARs="true" xmlNamespaceAware="false" 
      xmlValidation="false">
```

Please let me know if any other info is needed. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- What did you change in server.xml? (You're only giving one version, probably after your changes)
- What user do you run tomcat as? Is it possible that you did run tomcat as a different user - maybe root - earlier? In this case: Check ownership and permissions on liferay's "deploy" folder as well as tomcat's "webapps", "temp", "logs" and "work" folder.

If Liferay/Tomcat can't read and write to the "deploy" folder, it won't deploy anything

Edit: Also, check if you moved your Tomcat/Liferay installation. Liferay's `portal-setup-wizard.properties` (if you have this) has a setting for `liferay.home` - this points to the directory where Liferay expects the `deploy` folder. If you moved the installation to another location but keep this file unchanged, Liferay will still monitor the old location (including the old storage for document library and full-text index)

Comment: Please see below. I have made some changes and this particular error is resolved. I have started a new thread with regard to the new error...